# Invoke main thread method on eventhandler of another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have to update another GUI based on events raised by another object.

```
public void PLCMessage_Received(object sender, PLCMessageEventArgs e)
{
   string tempstr = (String)e.Message;
   UpdateGUI(tempstr);
}
public void UpdateGUI(string temp)
{
   if (temp == "A1Y101")
   {
     lbll2heartbeatack.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2heartbeatack.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2heartbeatack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
   else if (temp == "A1Y102")
   {
     lbll2chargeingscheduleack.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2chargeingscheduleack.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2chargeingscheduleack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
   else if (temp == "A1Y103")
   {
      lbll2productinfo.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2productinfo.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2productinfo.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
   else if (temp == "A1Y104")
   {
      lbll2entrytrackingack.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2entrytrackingack.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2entrytrackingack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
   else if (temp == "A1Y105")
   {
       lbll2exittrackinginfoack.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2exittrackinginfoack.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2exittrackinginfoack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
   else if (temp == "A1Y106")
   {
       lbll2rejectreqack.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate() { lbll2rejectreqack.Content = "Ack-OK"; lbll2rejectreqack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; }));
   }
}
```

There are more number of GUI controls which I have to update. For every control I writing th Invoke method.  Is it possible to call on main GUI so that i can GUI controls directly by their name?
Note: My application development is in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that purpose, that makes life easier.

```
private SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

public void PLCMessage_Received(object sender, PLCMessageEventArgs e)
{
    string tempstr = (String)e.Message;
    uiContext.Send((x)=> UpdateGUI(tempstr), null);//For synchronous
    //Or
    uiContext.Post((x)=> UpdateGUI(tempstr), null);//For Asynchronous
}
```

Bonus reading about [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: @Olivarsham Please take care that you do not remove links in the answer while you edit the formatting.

Comment: @Amar That's not his mistake, it is due to lack of mutual exclusion. I think both of us are editing at the same time :)

Comment: I saw this edit getting approved in the review queue. Thought I should point this out to the editor so that he can take care of it next time.

Comment: @Amar Agree with you, as I saw this immediately I had a chance to rollback, if not those links would have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void PLCMessage_Received(object sender, PLCMessageEventArgs e)
{
  string tempstr = (String)e.Message;
  App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => UpdateGUI(tempstr)); //Or BeginInvoke
}

public void UpdateGUI(string temp)
    {
        if (temp == "A1Y101")
        {
            lbll2heartbeatack.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2heartbeatack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; ;
        }
        else if (temp == "A1Y102")
        {
            lbll2chargeingscheduleack.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2chargeingscheduleack.Foreground = Brushes.Green; ;
        }
        else if (temp == "A1Y103")
        {
            lbll2productinfo.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2productinfo.Foreground = Brushes.Green;

        }
        else if (temp == "A1Y104")
        {
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if (temp == "A1Y105")
        {
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if (temp == "A1Y106")
        {
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Content = "Ack-OK";
            lbll2entrytrackingack.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        }
    }
```