# Alternative to Dispatcher class for .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher, bootstrapper, .net-framework-version

I'm new to threading. While learning from WPF sample (A Wix Bootstrapper application), I've came across the use of System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher in Run() method something like:

```
MyDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
.
.
//rest of the code 
.

Dispatcher.Run(); //This I believe invoke the app in a thread (plz correct me if I'm wrong).
```

**Requirement:** I'm trying to implement same in a Windows form application (Have to be for Net FW 2.0 for some reason), where I only have System.Threading namespace.

**Question:**How can I implement similar functionality like Dispatcher using System.Threading namespace?

Comment: i'm not following question, are you asking how do you invoke an operation on a new thread?

Comment: FYI, you're likely to have more problems than just `Dispatcher.Run`, coming from .NET 3.5 back to .NET 2.0.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20897956/2530848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample code for .NET 2.0

```
// Called from any method
new Thread(() => { UpdateRequest(); }).Start();

// Background activity
private void UpdateRequest() {
  UpdateUI("new text everytime" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

}

private void UpdateUI(string request)
{

  if (control.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke(new Delegate(UpdateUI), new object[] { request });
  }
 }
```

**Update**: Had accidentally used TPL as haven't used .NET 2.0 since long, replaced with native Threading

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` .Net 2.0 ?

Comment: Task factory TPL was not available in 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method and the [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property instead.